# How to solve Cauchy problem for $y'+2y= \exp(x)y^2 \quad y(1) = 1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

The original equation is $$y'+2y= \exp(x)y^2 \quad y(1) = 1$$

Well, this one is Bernulli's one, so I've put  $z = \frac{1}{z}$ therefore $z' = -\frac{y'}{y^2}$

and reduced it to the first-order non-linear equation:

$$z'-2z = -e^x$$

---

I've applied Lagrange's method

and found the solution (included variabled parameter):

$$y = \left(-\frac{1}{3}e^{-3x} + \alpha\right)e^{2x}$$

But I suspect some mistakes in the solution and not sure how to handle Cauchy's problem here :/

Answer (score 0):

You get
$$
(e^{-2x}z(x))'=e^{-2x}(z'(x)-2z(x))=-e^{-x}
$$
so that with $z(1)=1$ 
$$
e^{-2x}z(x)-e^{-2}=e^{-x}-e^{-1}
\implies z(x)=e^x+(e^{-2}-e^{-1})e^{2x}
\\~\\
\implies y(x)=\frac{e}{e^{x+1}-(e-1)e^{2x-1}}.
$$

Comment: is not my general solution wrong then? :/

Comment: Yes, it is. You seem to have some problem with mixing $y$ and $z$. Writing down some more steps of your solution process might help.

Comment: well, after rechecking I found out that $$y = \frac{1}{e^x(\alpha e^x+1)}$$

Comment: and applying given cauchy problem I got $$\alpha = \frac{1}{e^2} - \frac{1}{e}$$

Comment: Yes, that is what I wrote, only with the constants expressed differently. Closest in form is the expression for $z(x)$.